# CRON to Check if a webapp is working properly and report what happened if not

Tags: bash, apache-http-server, cron, status

This is my first iteration in bash:This webapp does not have postgres but Apache 2.4, Tomcat 8.

I check first the 200 http response. Then if http server is running and if the tomcat also does.

I should send a message by email and try to restart if any of the servers is down. If it does not result, another email would be sent.

Maybe could be easier if I just do a curl or wget and then check what happened with journalctl. But at the moment I cannot have journalctl at the server.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
SITE_UP_STATUS_GREP="HTTP/1.1\s200"

echo "* * * Start of Health Check * * *"
   
    MSG=""
    
    http200apache2=$(curl -I $WEBSITE  | grep -w $SITE_UP_STATUS_GREP)
    httpapache2=$(systemctl  is-active apache2 | grep  -w 'active')
    tomcat8=$(systemctl  is-active  tomcat8  | grep  -w 'active')
    
    
    MSG_HTTP="Apache substatus: "$(systemctl show -p SubState apache2)
    MSG_TC="Tomcat substatus: "$(systemctl show -p SubState tomcat8)
    echo "http-"$httpapache2
    echo "tc-"$tomcat8
    
    if [ -z "$http200apache2" ]; then
         if [ -z "$httpapache2" ] && [ -z "$tomcat8"  ]; then
              MSG="App - Status of servers Apache 2 and Tomcat 8: not active"$MSG_HTTP", "$MSG_TC  
         elif [ -z "$httpapache2"] && [ -n "$tomcat8"  ]; then
              MSG="App - Status of server Apache 2: not active"$MSG_HTTP  
         fi
    elif [ -z "$tomcat8" ]; then
         MSG="App - Status of  Tomcat 8: not active"$MSG_TC  
    fi
    echo $MSG
echo "* * * FIN * * *"
```

Comment: What parts are you stuck with?    I can see your script is not emailing messages - were you planning on relying on CRON to do that, and if so, why?   Likewise, I can't see any code to try restart the servers?   Are you expecting us to write your code for you?  We don't generally do that.

Comment: https://uptimerobot.com/

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstood. I know how to send the $MSG by email at a cron or restart the servers. I am stuck because I am not sure if I am doing the right thing.